# Issue regarding height of background video for Wide screens in Elementor

Tags: html, css, wordpress, video, elementor

Hy, hope this finds you well.

I have a query regarding a video background for wide/big screens. The thing is it is working fine for all devices in the elementor settings also in actual but for widescreen LCD, it is not showing in a complete page rather some portion of below section is also coming.

Please advise as width and height is adjusted for the widescreen option of elementor.

Before disabled plugins and changed the theme for one another issue which was related to this video.

link of website: [website link](https://beta.edgerope.com)

Attached picture of the LCD model details + how it looks.

[LCD Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vys4o.jpg)

[image: Red section should be down so that video can be seen in full page]

Appreciate if anyone know the solution, its done in elementor and on it, there is html code for buttons some images. Please see code if needed.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


<style type="text/css">


.hover {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}    
  
   
.hover:before {
  content: attr(data-hover);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
  width: max-content;
  background-color:;
  color: #ffff;
  justify-content: left;
  transition: opacity 1s pop-up;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 30em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size:25px;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -30px;
  top: -350px;
}

.hover:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
display: inline-block;
}
  
  
  .hover1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 
}    
  
   
.hover1:before {
  content: attr(data-hover);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
  width: max-content;
  background-color:;
  color: #ffff;
  justify-content: left;
  transition: opacity 1s pop-up;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 30em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size:25px;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -545px;
  top: -350px;
}

.hover1:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
display: inline-block;
}    


   .hover2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 
} 


.hover2:before {
  content: attr(data-hover);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
  width: max-content;
  background-color:;
  color: #ffff;
  justify-content: left;
  transition: opacity 1s pop-up;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 30em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size:25px;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left:-1060px;
  top: -350px;
}

.hover2:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
display: inline-block;
}    
    
.image{
   
  height: 800px;
  width:  100%;
 display:flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
     font-weight: normal;
    font-family:;
     color: #cccccc;
      font-size:28px;
    text-decoration: none;
   //display: grid;
  place-content:center;
  //justify-content:center;
    background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;

}


.training{
    
    padding-top: 550px;
  padding-right:470px;
  padding-left: 20px;


}
  .shop{
     padding-top: 550px;
     padding-left: 40px; 
  }
  
  .services{
      padding-top: 550px;
      padding-right:500px;
  }

 
.image>div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  
}

.image>div img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0;
 z-index: 0;
 display: inline-block;
}

.image>div span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image>div span:hover+img {
  opacity: 1;
   //cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
}






@media only screen and (max-width:2400px) and (min-width:1199px) {
 
    
.image{
  
  height: 800px;
  width:  100%;
 display:flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
     font-weight: normal;
    font-family:;
     color: #cccccc;
      font-size:28px;
    text-decoration: none;
   //display: grid;
  place-content:center;
  //justify-content:center;
    background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;

}


.training{
    

  padding-top: 500px;
  padding-right:420px;
  padding-left: 20px;


}
  .shop{
      min-width:10px;
     padding-top: 500px;
     padding-left: 50px; 
  }
  
  .services{
      padding-top: 500px;
      padding-right:450px;
  }

 
.image>div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  
}

.image>div img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0;
 z-index: 0;
 display: inline-block;
}

.image>div span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image>div span:hover+img {
  opacity: 1;
   //cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
}







@media only screen and (max-width:1366px) and (min-width:1170px) {
    
 

.hover {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 
}    
  
   
.hover:before {
  content: attr(data-hover);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
  width: max-content;
  background-color:;
  color: #ffff;
  justify-content: left;
  transition: opacity 1s pop-up;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 30em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size:25px;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -80px;
  top: -350px;
}

.hover:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
display: inline-block;
}
    
    
.hover1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 
}    
  
   
.hover1:before {
  content: attr(data-hover);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
  width: max-content;
  background-color:;
  color: #ffff;
  justify-content: left;
  transition: opacity 1s pop-up;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 30em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size:25px;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -545px;
  top: -350px;
}

.hover1:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
display: inline-block;
}    
    


.hover2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 
} 


.hover2:before {
  content: attr(data-hover);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
  width: max-content;
  background-color:;
  color: #ffff;
  justify-content: left;
  transition: opacity 1s pop-up;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 30em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size:25px;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -1000px;
  top: -350px;
}

.hover2:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
display: inline-block;
}    
    
    
    
    
.image{
   
  height: 800px;
  width:  100%;
 display:flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
     font-weight: normal;
    font-family:;
     color: #cccc;
      font-size:28px;
    text-decoration: none;
   //display: grid;
  place-content:center;
  //justify-content:center;
    background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;

}

.training{
    
  padding-top: 500px;
  padding-right:410px;
  padding-left: 65px;


}
  .shop{
     padding-top: 500px;
     padding-right:65px; 
  }
 
   .services{
      padding-top: 500px;
      padding-right:400px;
      padding-left: 0px;
  }

 
.image>div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  
}


.image>div img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0;
 z-index: 0;
 display: inline-block;
}

.image>div span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
 


.image>div span:hover+img {
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

}











@media only screen and (max-width:1200px) and (min-width:1000px) {
 .image{
   
  height: 800px;
  width:  100%;
 display:flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
     font-weight: normal;
    font-family:;
     color: #cccc;
      font-size:28px;
    text-decoration: none;
   //display: grid;
  place-content:center;
  //justify-content:center;
    background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;

}

.training{
    
  padding-top:   500px;
  padding-right: 350px;
  padding-left:  160px;


}
  .shop{
     padding-top: 500px;
     padding-left: 35px; 
  }
 
   .services{
      padding-top: 500px;
      padding-right:220px;
  }

 
.image>div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  
}

.image>div img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0;
 z-index: 0;
 display: inline-block;
}

.image>div span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
 


.image>div span:hover+img {
  opacity: 1;
   //cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

}






@media only screen and (max-width:1024px) and (min-width:768px) {
    
    .image{
   
  height: 800px;
  width:  100%;
 display:flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
     font-weight: normal;
    font-family:;
     color: #cccccc;
      font-size:28px;
    text-decoration: none;
   //display: grid;
  place-content:center;
  //justify-content:center;
    background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;

}

.training{
    
    padding-top: 500px;
  padding-right:260px;
  padding-left: 105px;


}
  .shop{
     padding-top: 500px;
     padding-left: 40px; 
     padding-right:130px;
  } 
    
    
       .services{
      padding-top: 500px;
      padding-right:200px;
      padding-left: 62px;
  }

 
.image>div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  
}

.image>div img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0;
 z-index: 0;
 display: inline-block;
}

.image>div span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
 


.image>div span:hover+img {
  opacity: 1;
   //cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

}
    
    @media only screen and (max-width:767px) {
    
      
    .image{
   
  height: 800px;
  width:  100%;
 display:flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
     font-weight: normal;
    font-family:;
     color: #cccccc;
      font-size:25px;
    text-decoration: none;
   //display: grid;
  place-content:center;
  //justify-content:center;
    background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;

}

.training{
    
    padding-top: 500px;
  padding-right:120px;
  padding-left: 0px;


}
  .shop{
     padding-top: 500px;
     padding-left: 20px; 
     padding-right:05px;
  } 
    
    
       .services{
      padding-top: 500px;
      padding-right:130px;
      padding-left:0px;
      margin: 0px;
  }
  
.image>div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  
}

.image>div img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0;
 z-index: 0;
 display: inline-block;
}

.image>div span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
 


.image>div span:hover+img {
  opacity: 1;
   //cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

}


</style>



</head>

<body>
    




<div class="image">
   
    
    <div class="services">
        
      <span class="hover" data-hover="We provide different services including  Inspection, Fabric Maintenance & Installation, Mechanical, Access Solutions and Design & Installation "
      
        onclick="window.location='https://beta.edgerope.com/services'">Services</span>
 
    <img src="http://beta.edgerope.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/2-1120x800.jpg"> 
   
    </div>
    
  
  
  
    
  <div class="training">
      
      <div>

</div>
       <span class="hover1" data-hover="We provide IRATA and SPRAT Training"  onclick="window.location='beta.edgerope.com/courses'">Training</span>

    
    <img src="http://beta.edgerope.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/1-1-1536x864.jpg"> </div>
    
    
    
    
  <div class="shop">
      
     <span class="hover2" data-hover="We are selling different rope access products through Salla Platform" onclick="window.location='beta.edgerope.com/shop'">Shop</span>
     
     
     
    <img src="http://beta.edgerope.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/1-1-1536x864.jpg"> </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the [encircled part](https://i.imgur.com/P6lxeXc.jpeg) the problem ? (Please check [How do I ask a good question ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to make a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use media query like this:

```
@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, by applying 16/9 the text in the background image is slighty up so it means this ratio is not good maybe, before in elementor, if I select the widescreen option the text was a bit down.  Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: Check your screen resolution from here: https://whatismyresolution.com

Comment: Thankyou @Afeef for the suggestion. I checked the LCD dimension its (1920 x 1080) so the media query will be like this ?    `@media screen (max-width:1920 px) and (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) `   or no need to add the width ? I tried to check in dev tool of chrome, looks fine there even without the aspect ratio but on LCD its not fine. Also this was the fault I see maybe there are other screens which have issue how can I achieve for all by applying max-width technique? Appreciate the response.

Comment: also the video I am playing from elementor as a background video option, in the code only images are defined which are appearing by hover.